$f : M → M$ is a diffeomorphism between odd dimensioned manifolds with only non-degenerate fixed points. Show that the number of fixed points is even.
This question is from an old publicly available qualifying exam that I’m using to learn this field (Stanford geometry and topology). I used Hatcher's book for reference. All work is my own, including my attempted proof.


Let $M$ be a closed, smooth, odd dimensional manifold, and $f : M → M$ a diffeomorphism with only non-degenerate fixed points. Show that the number of fixed points must be even.

Answer: A diffeomorphism induces isomorphisms of the homology groups of $M$, which corresponds to multiplying all betti numbers at once by some scalar. From Poincare duality, we know that for our Betti numbers, $b_{k} = b_{n-k}$. Our dimension is odd, so all nonzero betti numbers are symmetric. Were we to apply an alternating sum or scale an alternating sum, then each pair will cancel itself out.
As a result, we'll be left with zero for our Lefschetz number. Then the number of non-degenerate fixed points for our diffeomorphism will be zero, which is vacuously even.

(a) Is it actually true that the number of fixed points is zero? Would Poincare Duality followed by calculating the Lefschetz number actually work?
As a bonus, if there's another, more efficient method or theorem, let me know. I'm additionally concerned as to whether or not my interpretation of the traces of the diffeomorphism only scaling the homology groups (by degree) is correct and applicable here under the diffeomorphism.

First: Why are all the multiples the same? (This is certainly false in many cases.) Second: If the Lefschetz number is nonzero, there must be a fixed point. The converse is not necessarily valid.

Is there a reason you are duplicating this recent question? And your attempted solution makes no sense.

@TedShifrin I was having trouble with the trace computation of a linear map. Any resources that give explicit computations would be appreciated. However, since we have an isomorphism of homology groups, and the property of Poincare duality should be preserved (right?) then at the very least the $k$th and $n-k$th Betty numbers need to have the same value, (by implication scaling), right?

@TedShifrin Also I read through a number of the review books, but I didn’t see anything regarding the backwards implication of L fixed point theorem. Where would backwards implication not hold?

@MoisheKohan I didn’t see that attempted solution, but it doesn’t have an answer on that page and the person’s attempted proof initially seems different (although they seemed to edit it and say they were attempting to prove via L number). This is a solution verification question that I’m asking, so it’s more about my unique proof than anything else.

Yes, $b_k=b_{n-k}$. For a map $f:\Bbb CP^n\to\Bbb CP^n$, cohomology ring structure will tell you that if $f^*$ is multiplication by $d$ on $H^2$, then it is multiplication by $d^n$ on $H^{2n}$. You can translate this by duality into a homology computation. For your comment, the Lefschetz number is a net signed intersection number; there can be fixed points where these intersection numbers sum to $0$.

@TedShifrin I see, I did read Guillemin and Pollacks book, which is where I saw this theorem first. I thought the criteria where it works is when I have finite, disjoint fixed points. I interpreted this as being true here from the “non-degenerate” fixed point criteria in the problem statement. Is the non-degenerate condition in the problem statement not strong enough to prevent us from counting using Lefschetz number?

Absolutely not. This is a question of signs.

@TedShifrin I’m moving across country but I’ll read through the chapter again when I’m done in a few days.  If we have a net sign summation of zero, then we need two cancelling intersections? Then net zero L number must imply an even number of intersections? I believe Guil. and Poll. addressed something like that by counting intersections mod 2, if I remember. So 0 L number at least implies evenness? If so I think that would complete the proof.

Yes, except for your issue with the traces and “the same scalar.”  Safe move!
